# Annotation processor not working with Compiler API - Java

Tags: java, lombok, java-compiler-api

I have a task to compile java source file from source code. So I used JavaCompiler API. My java class annotated with Lombok annotation @Data. But when I compiled class exceptions are thrown.

Name.java

```
package com.pojo;

import java.lang.String;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Name {
  private String last;

  private String first;
}
```

here is my code that's compile Name.java

```
String fileToCompile = "/com/pojo/Name.java";

        File file = new File(fileToCompile);

        JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
        StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(null, null, null);
        fileManager.setLocation(StandardLocation.CLASS_OUTPUT, Arrays.asList(new File("/home/")));

        Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> jf = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromFiles(Arrays.asList(file));

        List<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add("-processor");
        options.add("lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor");


        // Compile the file
        compiler.getTask(null,
                fileManager,
                null,
                options,
                null,
                jf)
        .call();

        fileManager.close();
```

Exception:

> warning: Can't initialize javac processor due to (most likely) a
>   class loader problem: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/sun/tools/javac/processing/JavacProcessingEnvironment public class
>   Name {
>          ^      at lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor.getJavacProcessingEnvironment(LombokProcessor.java:423)
>     at lombok.javac.apt.LombokProcessor.init(LombokProcessor.java:90)
>     at
>   lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor$JavacDescriptor.want(AnnotationProcessor.java:124)
>     at lombok.core.AnnotationProcessor.init(AnnotationProcessor.java:177)
>     at
>   lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor.init(AnnotationProcessor.java:73)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$ProcessorState.(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:500)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$DiscoveredProcessors$ProcessorStateIterator.next(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:597)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.discoverAndRunProcs(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:690)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.access$1800(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:91)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment$Round.run(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1035)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment.doProcessing(JavacProcessingEnvironment.java:1176)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.processAnnotations(JavaCompiler.java:1170)
>     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.main.JavaCompiler.compile(JavaCompiler.java:856)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.main.Main.compile(Main.java:523)     at
>   com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.doCall(JavacTaskImpl.java:129)
>     at com.sun.tools.javac.api.JavacTaskImpl.call(JavacTaskImpl.java:138)
>     at com.pojo.CompilerTest.main(CompilerTest.java:55)   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.sun.tools.javac.processing.JavacProcessingEnvironment     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   lombok.launch.ShadowClassLoader.loadClass(ShadowClassLoader.java:530) 
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)    ... 17
>   more 1 warning

Comment: Are you running this with the JDK or JRE?

Comment: I added tools.jar in JRE

Comment: Ok if tools.jar is on the classpath that should work, but maybe try with the JDK

Comment: how to try with  JDK?

Comment: What JRE/JDK version are you using?

Comment: Java 8 and I tried with Lombok 1.16, 1.18 and edge as well

Comment: Wiill you get this even without any lombok annotations on class and options on javacompiler?

Comment: @pirho if I remove '@Data' annotation from Name.java then a class is compiled successfully